# iOSアプリ開発 tableviewcellが機種によっては表示できる数が違うのでどうすればいいか

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

iPhone 8等でtableviewcellを表示しようとしたのですがスクロールして最後の方に入っている要素が選択できませんでした。
iPhone 12とかでは選択できます。どうしたらいいでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

具体的なコードやSwiftUIかUIKitなのかの情報がないので答えにくいですが、
UIKitでStoryboardを使って開発している場合は、AutoLayoutが機能していない可能性があります。

以下の記事を参照してみてください

- [Swift学習者必見！アプリ開発の基礎AutoLayoutの使い方](https://www.sejuku.net/blog/11075)
- [【swift】 autolayoutしてみた-基礎編-](https://qiita.com/naoking21/items/08932587b9fdb337b3df)